# IFrame facebook app with httpS

Tags: facebook, iframe, https

Is there a way to run an HTTP**S** application as IFrame facebook app? if not, how can i prevent replay attacks and make sure that the content passed between the browser and the server is not captured.
Also, is it possible to have Ajax calls to the server going over secure channel?

Thanks,
Pomponius.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set your canvas URL to an https url. However, you are going to run into a number issues such as the Facebook Javascript SDK is not hosted on https. Also, you should be aware that Facebook itself is susceptible to relay attacks so you aren't really going to be able to fully mitigate the problem. As far as making AJAX calls to your server you have complete control over that so as long as your client side javascript and your server support this then it won't be a problem.